# Unable to access voice assistant button in firefox browser

Tags: next.js

I try to implement voice assistant button for my project on nextjs.I implemented speechrecognition api and speechsynthesis api are working for chrome browser and its incognito mode also but it is not working in firefox browser.I am getting console text as "SpeechRecognition is not supported in this browser.".Hence I tried with diffferent npm packages like annyang,artyom.js and responsivevoice are not working.

I tried with diffferent npm packages like annyang,artyom.js and responsivevoice are not working.I need to implement the supportive library to build voice assistant button accessible for all browsers.